# Python script to answer Rosalind test 2 (sum of two squares)

Tags: python

The test: https://rosalind.info/problems/ini2/

> #### Problem
>
> Given: Two positive integers *a* and *b*, each less than 1000.
> Return: The integer corresponding to the square of the hypotenuse of
> the right triangle whose legs
> have lengths *a* and *b*.
>
> #### Sample Dataset
>
> ```
> 3 5
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 34
> ```

My script:

```
#!/bin/env python3
import argparse
import os.path
import sys

def int_sq(n):
    return int(n)**2

def square_hyp_triangle(a,b):
    #check int
    sq_sum=sum(int_sq(i) for i in [a,b]) 
    return sq_sum


def main(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            prog="intro",
            description='Import a file with integers')
    
    parser.add_argument('filename', 
                        type=argparse.FileType('r'), 
                        nargs='?',
                        help='an existing filename')

    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    if not args.filename:
        sys.exit("Please provide an input file, or pipe it via stdin")

    for line in args.filename:
        line = line.rstrip().split()
        res = square_hyp_triangle(line[0],line[1])
        #print(line[0], line[1])
        print(res)
    #print(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you saved the above script named `intro.py`
You can run it :

```shell
echo "3 5" | ./intro.py -
```

Which parts can be improved?

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). You can ask a follow up question with a link back to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imports are sorted -- nice!

---

## optional type hinting

```
def int_sq(n):
```

Consider using this signature:

```
def int_sq(n: float) -> int:
```

(Recall that `float` [includes](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower)
`int` for hinting purposes.)

---

## sum, map

```
    sq_sum = sum(int_sq(i) for i in [a, b])
```

Consider phrasing this as

```
    sq_sum = sum(map(int_sq, [a, b]))
```

since the temp var `i` is uninteresting and could be anonymous.

Also, delete the meaningless "#check int" comment.
And maybe just `return` the expression without giving it a name.

---

## docstring

The identifier `square_hyp_triangle` is fine.
But *do* write an English sentence for it:

```
def square_hyp_triangle(a: float, b: float) -> float:
    """Finds the squared length of a triangle's hypotenuse.
    """
```

Consider writing another few lines so that
[$ python -m doctest *.py](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html)
does an automated test to verify things work as intended.

```
    """Finds the squared length of a triangle's hypotenuse.

    >>> square_hyp_triangle(3, 5)
    34
    """
```

---

## typer

In `main` the parser is nice enough,
though "import" perhaps is a slightly odd verb.
I'm glad you're using that library; it reduces the documentation burden for end users.
Consider switching to [typer](https://pypi.org/project/typer),
which gives you similar functionality "for free" (if you're using type hints).

I'm slightly surprised by the absence of `... , default=sys.stdin)`,
but I guess your defaulting must work fine.
The `filename` identifier seems to have the wrong name,
given that you want it be an open file descriptor rather than a name.

In `line.rstrip().split()` maybe you had some CR/LF trouble?
I don't see why you need to strip, given that split will discard whitespace for you.

---

## tuple unpack

Avoid cryptic `[0]` / `[1]` subscripts,
preferring `a, b = line.split()`.
Or better, convert from `str` right here using:

```
        a, b = map(float, line.split())
```

Aha, now I understand that `return int(n)**2` expression.
That doesn't seem a very sensible place to do the conversion.
I wouldn't really expect that a function could square `"3"`.
And even if it did, should I get back `"9"` instead of `9`?
Best to not even explore such territory, and stick to numeric values,
so the squaring function has a
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
and is not also responsible for type conversions.
Better to allocate that responsibility to the CLI interface called `main`.

Rejecting fractional inputs like `3.1` is maybe an unusual design choice.
Guess it stems from the "Given:" and "Return:" parts of the spec, OK.
Rosalind's "download a one-line text file dataset" requirement
pushes this code in a slightly odd direction.

---

## old debugs

```
        #print(line[0], line[1])
```

It served a purpose at one time.
But now that your code is "done" and you're requesting review,
it is the right time to tidy up and delete debug statements.

---

> Which parts can be improved?

Adhere to Single Responsibility.

Recommend you adopt [black](https://pypi.org/project/black)
auto-formatting, so expressions have a uniform appearance
without even having to think about it.

Comment: Hello @J_H, would you be kind to elaborate on the `... , default=sys.stdin)`
I have mainly used stackoverflow to find a way to read from a file with `argparse`  but it didn't have this `default` argument.
Maybe point me to another post?

Comment: I just took it literally from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs). (I used to use argparse all the time, but nowadays I can usually go the lazy route of relying on `import typer` which does most of the heavy lifting for me.) The documentation example includes a call to `parser.add_argument(... , default=sys.stdin)`

Answer (score 3):

**The command-line usage is awkward**. Your program needs two arguments: `a`
and `b`. In a case like that, the easiest thing to do is configure `argparse`
– no surprises here – to take two arguments. Instead, you have set things up
so that the user must either put the two integers in a file and pass the file
path as an argument or to use the piped-echo approach illustrated in your demo
usage.

**The awkward command-line usage also forces you to parse text**. But that's
all unnecessary if you just do the natural thing: take two arguments.

**Whenever feasible, let argparse enforce the usage requirements.** Your
program requires `a` and `b`. There's no escaping that. Make the arguments
required.

**Whenever feasible, let argparse enforce data types.** Same idea. Your program
wants integers. Configure argparse with that detail and let the library do the
work for you.

**Move command line argument parsing out of `main()`**. This is just a good
habit to get into. It allows you to test/debug the command-line interface
separately, if needed, and it keeps `main()` focused narrowly on its primary
job: top-level program orchestration.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import sys

def main(args):
    opts = parse_args(args)
    ss = sum_of_squares(opts.a, opts.b)
    print(ss)

def parse_args(args):
    ap = ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument('a', type = int)
    ap.add_argument('b', type = int)
    return ap.parse_args(args)

def sum_of_squares(*xs):
    return sum(x ** 2 for x in xs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Unless CPython has changed in recent versions, `sum([x ** 2 for x in xs])` [should be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62709748/6243352) than `sum(x ** 2 for x in xs)`.

Comment: As a note to this review, if you have your arguments in a file, then we can convert _externally_ to command-line arguments - e.g. `xargs <file intro.py`.  In my opinion, that's better than reimplementing this functionality in your program(s).

Answer (score 1):

- Don't parse command line arguments manually. Consider **[docopt](http://docopt.org)** instead.
- Usually I advocate a *more functions, please* approach. In this case it seems you went a bit too far. I see no benefits of wrapping operator `**` into a function.
- **`int()`** may throw `ValueError`, which will terminate the script prematurely. Be prepared, and catch it.

Comment: Hello vnp, I am a bit confused by the "Don't parse command line arguments manually."
Isn't the argparse the method that generally is used to parse command line arguments in python scripts? Isn't it manually either using `docopt` or `argparse`?

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. Perhaps _manual_ was bad wording. `argparse` requires much more code. In my opinion `docopt` is just  cleaner.